# Put all pages under current WordPress parent slug to new post type slug

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

On a WordPress website, I have a lot of pages under `/current-slug/` and created a new post type with `/new-slug/` and I want to move or import everything under `/current-slug/` to `/new-slug/` so that in the WP Admin the `/current-slug/` pages are not accessible under pages, but now in the new post type new-slug admin area.

Is this possible without a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Changing post types

If you have actually created a new post type and want the posts of an old type to appear under the new type, you can do exactly that. The slug of the new post type will then be used.

Because you mentioned, that you want to solve the problem without a plugin, the easiest way is to execute SQL against your database table:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type="{new_post_type}" WHERE post_type="{old_post_type}";
```

Before executing the above SQL, make sure to swap out `{old_post_type}` and `{new_post_type}` for the actual names of your post types, since you have only mentioned their slugs.

Note, that the above SQL will switch **all posts** of the old post_type to the new one.

Also note, that the statement assumes the standard table prefix `wp_`is being used.

### Moving to a different parent page

It came up in the comments, that the question might be actually about moving posts to a different parent page.

You can also solve this using a simple SQL statement:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_parent={new_parent_id} WHERE post_parent={old_parent_id} AND post_type="page";
```

Again, make sure to replace `{new_parent_id}` with the ID of the new parent post and `{old_parent_id}` with the ID of the current parent post. You can find them by looking at the parameter inside the URL when editing the old and new parent.

Note that I am now assuming that we are talking about the `post_type` of `page`, you can change that accordingly, but make sure to specify it, to not also move attachments etc to the new parent post.

Also, again note that the standard table prefix `wp_` is assumed.

### Moving child pages to a custom post type

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_parent=0, post_type="{new_post_type}" WHERE post_parent={old_parent_post_id} AND post_type="{old_post_type}";
```

You have to put in the old parent post id, which you can find as stated above, the current post type, which is probably "page", and the new post type (not the slug of the post type), which you have newly created.

Before executing the query, it might help to do a SELECT query and check whether you are updating the correct posts. To do that, just create one with the same WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent={old_parent_post_id} AND post_type="{old_post_type}";
```

Comment: Here is some more context the current posts live under that old slug, but that is just a parent page under the WordPress pages. The current posts are not technically its own post type, they are in pages. I will give this a shot on the dev environment.

Comment: SQL query:
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type="coaches" WHERE post_type="staff"
Matched rows: 0

Comment: You have to make your question more clear. Are we talking about post types at all or do you just have a group of pages, which should reside under a different parent page? Your question sounded like a conversion from one post type to another. Your comment says you want to move them from child pages of a parent page to a post type. I am suspecting you just want to move them to a different parent page.

Comment: Apologies. I want to move that group of child pages to a new custom post type. So pulling them out of pages to their own custom post type which is already set up.

Comment: No worries, I added all three options, the last one is the one you want.

Comment: I love you. I've been searching everywhere to figure this out. I will be more clear and I really, really, really appreciate this. Works perfectly.